Companion on Docker - runs in Permisson Error
I'm trying to run Bitcodus - Companion on Docker.
I pulled this image and tried to start the Conatiner, but it gives me this error in the Logs:
2024-09-07T11:29:40.580Z info Log/Controller Application starting 
Failed to create config directory. Do you have the correct permissions?

I'm pretty new to Docker, and i don't really know what to look at first. Search-function does not really give me any hints.
Using Portainer
The container runs, but gives this error in a loop
Config:
{
"AppArmorProfile": "",
"Args": [
    "sh",
    "-c",
    "./node-runtime/bin/node ./main.js --admin-address 0.0.0.0 --admin-port 8000 --config-dir $COMPANION_CONFIG_BASEDIR --extra-module-path /app/module-local-dev"
],
"Config": {
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "Cmd": [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "./node-runtime/bin/node ./main.js --admin-address 0.0.0.0 --admin-port 8000 --config-dir $COMPANION_CONFIG_BASEDIR --extra-module-path /app/module-local-dev"
    ],
    "Domainname": "",
    "Entrypoint": [
        "/docker-entrypoint.sh"
    ],
    "Env": [
        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/app/node-runtime/bin",
        "COMPANION_CONFIG_BASEDIR=/companion"
    ],
    "ExposedPorts": {
        "16622/tcp": {},
        "28492/tcp": {},
        "8000/tcp": {}
    },
    "Healthcheck": {
        "Interval": 30000000000,
        "Retries": 3,
        "StartPeriod": 5000000000,
        "Test": [
            "CMD",
            "curl",
            "-fSsq",
            "http://localhost:8000/"
        ],
        "Timeout": 3000000000
    },
    "Hostname": "0f1dc43b191b",
    "Image": "docker.io/ghcr.io/bitfocus/companion/companion:3.4.0-7266-main-2c2d3e71",
    "Labels": {
        "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2024-09-07T01:44:53.210Z",
        "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Bitfocus Companion enables the reasonably priced Elgato Streamdeck and other controllers to be a professional shotbox surface for an increasing amount of different presentation switchers, video playback software and broadcast equipment.",
        "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "NOASSERTION",
        "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "2c2d3e71468a336c4bbabb2c58c08364fa7597d6",
        "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/bitfocus/companion",
        "org.opencontainers.image.title": "companion",
        "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/bitfocus/companion",
        "org.opencontainers.image.version": "main"
    },
    "OnBuild": null,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "User": "companion",
    "Volumes": {
        "/companion": {}
    },
    "WorkingDir": "/app"
},
"Created": "2024-09-07T11:20:41.382588036Z",
"Driver": "overlay2",
"ExecIDs": null,
"GraphDriver": {
    "Data": {
        "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/517f8687ca9d7318b07d1e04f914d54d71f8faa0db6ab65a6c4ef8af4ace40af-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebbebded3b30386915dac2e3f623c17cd0153fffa9c7f3c8128944073faeef3f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ce13963ef1bcd5b18145ab660bdc19ad1f579294cbfa42ddec935e83d3dad895/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/197b62f0d1832a854e3ee36842813a432943b3c51590b7ab10b1696eb58a4aa6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/77bc08b249519f9c1dfbabaad80cd2a05f273f8569e6c422372d98f8d8fc582a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fb385e7665c6b3be5d2907adaa2d02a29168814a027ab9b4a507bc8fe97862ac/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dee3e80575c101abac7e5aaf5921936b35baf5f6ba95017aa2480941229029c5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b62e47acb792741e83be5975435fb480d123f735f0531e27c9a2a55ea05e3494/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/227b68247d95b3af5b7251de164ce360d2f24b16c68bfe8da68d1e3ca63d5735/diff",
        "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/517f8687ca9d7318b07d1e04f914d54d71f8faa0db6ab65a6c4ef8af4ace40af/merged",
        "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/517f8687ca9d7318b07d1e04f914d54d71f8faa0db6ab65a6c4ef8af4ace40af/diff",
        "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/517f8687ca9d7318b07d1e04f914d54d71f8faa0db6ab65a6c4ef8af4ace40af/work"
    },
    "Name": "overlay2"
},
"HostConfig": {
    "AutoRemove": false,
    "Binds": [
        "/home/pi/companion:/companion"
    ],
    "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
    "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
    "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
    "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
    "BlkioWeight": 0,
    "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
    "CapAdd": [
        "AUDIT_WRITE",
        "CHOWN",
        "DAC_OVERRIDE",
        "FOWNER",
        "FSETID",
        "KILL",
        "MKNOD",
        "NET_BIND_SERVICE",
        "NET_RAW",
        "SETFCAP",
        "SETGID",
        "SETPCAP",
        "SETUID",
        "SYS_CHROOT"
    ],
    "CapDrop": [
        "AUDIT_CONTROL",
        "BLOCK_SUSPEND",
        "DAC_READ_SEARCH",
        "IPC_LOCK",
        "IPC_OWNER",
        "LEASE",
        "LINUX_IMMUTABLE",
        "MAC_ADMIN",
        "MAC_OVERRIDE",
        "NET_ADMIN",
        "NET_BROADCAST",
        "SYSLOG",
        "SYS_ADMIN",
        "SYS_BOOT",
        "SYS_MODULE",
        "SYS_NICE",
        "SYS_PACCT",
        "SYS_PTRACE",
        "SYS_RAWIO",
        "SYS_RESOURCE",
        "SYS_TIME",
        "SYS_TTY_CONFIG",
        "WAKE_ALARM"
    ],
    "Cgroup": "",
    "CgroupParent": "",
    "CgroupnsMode": "private",
    "ConsoleSize": [
        0,
        0
    ],
    "ContainerIDFile": "",
    "CpuCount": 0,
    "CpuPercent": 0,
    "CpuPeriod": 0,
    "CpuQuota": 0,
    "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
    "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
    "CpuShares": 0,
    "CpusetCpus": "",
    "CpusetMems": "",
    "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
    "DeviceRequests": [],
    "Devices": [],
    "Dns": [],
    "DnsOptions": null,
    "DnsSearch": null,
    "ExtraHosts": [],
    "GroupAdd": null,
    "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
    "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
    "Init": false,
    "IpcMode": "private",
    "Isolation": "",
    "Links": null,
    "LogConfig": {
        "Config": {},
        "Type": "json-file"
    },
    "MaskedPaths": [
        "/proc/asound",
        "/proc/acpi",
        "/proc/kcore",
        "/proc/keys",
        "/proc/latency_stats",
        "/proc/timer_list",
        "/proc/timer_stats",
        "/proc/sched_debug",
        "/proc/scsi",
        "/sys/firmware"
    ],
    "Memory": 0,
    "MemoryReservation": 0,
    "MemorySwap": 0,
    "MemorySwappiness": null,
    "NanoCpus": 0,
    "NetworkMode": "bridge",
    "OomKillDisable": null,
    "OomScoreAdj": 0,
    "PidMode": "",
    "PidsLimit": null,
    "PortBindings": {
        "16622/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "",
                "HostPort": "16622"
            }
        ],
        "8000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "",
                "HostPort": "8001"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Privileged": false,
    "PublishAllPorts": false,
    "ReadonlyPaths": [
        "/proc/bus",
        "/proc/fs",
        "/proc/irq",
        "/proc/sys",
        "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
    ],
    "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
    "RestartPolicy": {
        "MaximumRetryCount": 0,
        "Name": "unless-stopped"
    },
    "Runtime": "runc",
    "SecurityOpt": null,
    "ShmSize": 67108864,
    "UTSMode": "",
    "Ulimits": null,
    "UsernsMode": "",
    "VolumeDriver": "",
    "VolumesFrom": null
},
"HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/94b00696cee30adff6ac71607f82c2df9b7f100b2dda4ee6eeae0c7c338ea5c8/hostname",
"HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/94b00696cee30adff6ac71607f82c2df9b7f100b2dda4ee6eeae0c7c338ea5c8/hosts",
"Id": "94b00696cee30adff6ac71607f82c2df9b7f100b2dda4ee6eeae0c7c338ea5c8",
"Image": "sha256:b51d968d869bf2da98d61256da3a70179347f1eb385122a722bd287f5990a33d",
"LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/94b00696cee30adff6ac71607f82c2df9b7f100b2dda4ee6eeae0c7c338ea5c8/94b00696cee30adff6ac71607f82c2df9b7f100b2dda4ee6eeae0c7c338ea5c8-json.log",
"MountLabel": "",
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Destination": "/companion",
        "Mode": "",
        "Propagation": "rprivate",
        "RW": true,
        "Source": "/home/pi/companion",
        "Type": "bind"
    }
],
"Name": "/companion",
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
        "bridge": {
            "Aliases": null,
            "DriverOpts": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAMConfig": {},
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "Links": null,
            "MacAddress": "",
            "NetworkID": "a614605d3456a6616ca61876ffc7b34275b6e7dd666703beac2eab16ee565c5e"
        }
    },
    "Ports": {},
    "SandboxID": "314028fc79728c2fa0a8da8ccca777382e2bd552c96453507cc6abd0f1b18337",
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/314028fc7972",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null
},
"Path": "/docker-entrypoint.sh",
"Platform": "linux",
"Portainer": {
    "ResourceControl": {
        "Id": 27,
        "ResourceId": "94b00696cee30adff6ac71607f82c2df9b7f100b2dda4ee6eeae0c7c338ea5c8",
        "SubResourceIds": [],
        "Type": 1,
        "UserAccesses": [],
        "TeamAccesses": [],
        "Public": false,
        "AdministratorsOnly": true,
        "System": false
    }
},
"ProcessLabel": "",
"ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/94b00696cee30adff6ac71607f82c2df9b7f100b2dda4ee6eeae0c7c338ea5c8/resolv.conf",
"RestartCount": 13,
"State": {
    "Dead": false,
    "Error": "",
    "ExitCode": 1,
    "FinishedAt": "2024-09-07T11:34:00.685757986Z",
    "Health": {
        "FailingStreak": 0,
        "Log": [],
        "Status": "unhealthy"
    },
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Paused": false,
    "Pid": 0,
    "Restarting": true,
    "Running": true,
    "StartedAt": "2024-09-07T11:33:58.485030902Z",
    "Status": "restarting"
}

}

do you have this folder /home/pi/companion in your system ?? if yes can you check the permission of this folder and paste it here

the folder /home/pi/companion was created by root. Edited the permisson
Thank you @0xn0b174
